# Invert an Excel function containing the tangent

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

In the following excel formula:

```
=95*1*1/TAN(RADIANS(M3-(10.3/2.01)))/5280)
```

$M3=2.63715$

and let's say the result of this formula is:
$5.508306483$

What would this formula be if I needed to solve for `M3`?

Comment: RADIANS is just multiplication by $\pi/180$, right? Then you can probably put $y= 91\cdot \dots$ into Wolfram Alpha and ask it to solve for $m$.

Comment: thanks Pizza, do you happen to know the excel formula to accomplish this.